# unable to invoke `unload` js event

Tags: javascript

I have a page where I invoke the following:

```
window.addEventListener("load", do_something_load);
window.addEventListener("unload", do_something_unload);

function do_something_load() {
    console.log('[load] inside function!');
};

function do_something_unload() {
    console.log('[unload] inside function!');
};
```

For some reason, I am never able to get the `unload` event to work and thus `do_something_unload` never seems to get called.

I am quite new to JS, and have spent 2 hours seraching for a solution for this!

Comment: You may give a try to [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) for that..

Comment: is it typo at window.addEventListener("unload", so something_unload); in function name it should be do_something_unload ?

Comment: @JadavPalak: apologies, it was a typo - corrected it now

Comment: @Keff hmm.. why? `unload` is the correct function I'd say for this..

Comment: try it by callback-functions according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: @JadavPalak on the page you link, it clearly states `Typically, it is better to use window.addEventListener() and the unload event, instead of onunload.`

Comment: @JohnJ Yup, you are right, only difference would be that `beforeunload` is cancelable, in case you want to prevent navigation or something.

Comment: @Keff hmm.. then why wouldnt this work?!? when I call the `do_something_unload` function on the console it seems to work fine..

Comment: Yes, it will work, i'm sorry for the confusion. I just wanted to point out if you want to prevent unload, you should use `beforeunload`.

Comment: never used that 'unload' event, tried some random code I found here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/Events/unload , im seeing the logs in the console for both beforeunload and unload event, but they disappear of the console almost a milisecond after theyre being printed

Comment: @BenoitF: You are correct, but my unload function writes stuff to indexDB, so I know if the code is exceuted or not. As I said, when I run it through the console, it writes to the DB etc.. So the code works.. but the function is not fired after the `unload` event.